# Render RABL template with two objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I recently came across a condition were i wanted to send two objects in the RABL as a response.

```
[
 {
   id: "1",
   name: "XYZ"
 },
 {
   id: "1",
   name: "XYZ"
 },
 {
   total: "2"
 }
]
```

All I could manage was this , which is not correct.

```
[
 {
   id: "1",
   name: "XYZ",
   total: "2"
 },
 {
   id: "1",
   name: "XYZ",
   total: "2"
 }
]
```

I Found a solution which was to use a partial to iterate on the object and just add a new

```
node(:name) {partial("users/names", :object => @users)}
node(:total){ @total}
```

This is a hack, which i don't want because it wraps all the names in a node .
Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: add your action code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your rabl file try this:

```ruby
child @users, object_root: false do
    attributes :id, :name
end
node(:total) { @users.size }
```